# Why do my array.size() give wrong value?

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an instance of `ArrayList` named `array`.
When I parse some JSON data it will store it all in `array`.
When I do a `System.out.println(array);` it will list a long list of items, around 30, but when I write `System.out.println(array.size);` it will give the value one.

How come it only gives me the value 1 when the list contains at least 30 values?

My code for this:

```
public void setLocationName (String name) {
    array = new ArrayList<String>();
    array.add(name);
    System.out.println(array); //This return a long list
    System.out.println(array.size()); //But this only return the value 1
}

public String[] getLocationName() {
    String tArray[] = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++){
      System.out.println(i);
      tArray = array.toArray(new String[i]);    
    }       
    return tArray;
}
```

}

The long list :

```
[Brunnsparken, Göteborg]
[Brunnsgatan, Göteborg]
[Brunnslyckan, Lerum]
[Brunnsbotorget, Göteborg]
[Brunnsnäs, Ulricehamn]
[Brunnshult, Mellerud]
[Brunnsdal, Skövde]
[Brunns skola, Ulricehamn]
[Brunnsgården, Kungälv]
[Brunns kyrka, Ulricehamn]
[Boråsparken, Borås]
[Stadsparken, Ulricehamn]
[Lysekilsparken, Lysekil]
[Mössebergsparken, Falköping]
[Dalaborgsparken, Vänersborg]
[Rösparken, Åmål]
[Lillhagsparken Norra, Göteborg]
[Lillhagsparken Södra, Göteborg]
[Sylte Ryrbäcksparken, Trollhättan]
[Skogstomtsparken, Borås]
[Svinesundsparken, Norge]
[Håjumsparken, Trollhättan]
[Eriksdalsparken, Bollebygd]
[Fridhemsparken, Lidköping]
```

My result will be that only one item from the list will be returned in the `tArray` but I wanna return the whole list.

How to solve this?

Comment: You're creating a new array and adding 1 element to it - therefore, it's always, at the point you're printing out the size, going to only have 1 element in it.

Comment: What do you mean by _This return a long list_? You create a `new ArrayList` then `add` one item. There is no way it can contain a long list. Please post an example of `name`.

Comment: When I printe System.out.println(array); it gived a long list I posted it above

Comment: Please provide an example.

Comment: What is the content of the string parsed to the setter?

Comment: String name  =(String) jsonObj.get("name");

Comment: exactly, so you are only parsing one element. Build your array/List first and just parse that (Obviously changing your setter to accomodate).

Answer (score 4):

Java doesn't understand `Json` and basically what you're doing is add a string to an array

`this.array.add(name);` ---> add one value to the array, therefore the size is just one

you may need to use a specific `Json` library to parse the data in to an java arraylist.

regards

Comment: So I have to split the String

Comment: yes, but you might have to do it by hand. Welcome to world of java =)

Answer (score 0):

```
public void setLocationName (String name) {
    array = new ArrayList<String>();
    array.add(name);
    System.out.println(array); //This return a long list
    System.out.println(array.size()); //But this only return the value 1
}
```

You are creating a new `ArrayList` each time you call this method:

`array = new ArrayList<String>();`

You could just remove the above line, however I suggest you rename the method as this is no longer a setter and you are in fact now adding to an existing list each time you call this method.

I suggest what you want to do is build your List before parsing to the setter, perhaps using a [`foreach` loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html) (I'm not sure what kind of object you are working with) and simplify your setter (`setLocationName`) to accomodate.

So it would become:

```
public void setLocationName(ArrayList<String> names)
    {
        this.array = names;
        System.out.println(array); //This return a long list
        System.out.println(array.size()); //But this only return the value 1
    }
```

Comment: Actually just moving the arrayList solved the whole problem :-) Now my combobox display all the items from my JSON. You solved it.

Comment: Problem by doing that is that you no longer have a traditional `setter` as you are actually now contributing to an existing list each time you call this method. So perhaps you should rename the method to something else at least.

Comment: Perhaps you should give this person credit for solving your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Look like you need to parse the `String` into pairs.

Looks to me like a `Map` might be the most appropriate structure to store the data in - I presume the first part from the value is unique.

Regex is probably the best approach to parsing the data:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    final String data = "[Brunnsparken, Göteborg]\n"
            + "[Brunnsgatan, Göteborg]\n"
            + "[Brunnslyckan, Lerum]\n"
            + "[Brunnsbotorget, Göteborg]\n"
            + "[Brunnsnäs, Ulricehamn]\n"
            + "[Brunnshult, Mellerud]\n"
            + "[Brunnsdal, Skövde]\n"
            + "[Brunns skola, Ulricehamn]\n"
            + "[Brunnsgården, Kungälv]\n"
            + "[Brunns kyrka, Ulricehamn]\n"
            + "[Boråsparken, Borås]\n"
            + "[Stadsparken, Ulricehamn]\n"
            + "[Lysekilsparken, Lysekil]\n"
            + "[Mössebergsparken, Falköping]\n"
            + "[Dalaborgsparken, Vänersborg]\n"
            + "[Rösparken, Åmål]\n"
            + "[Lillhagsparken Norra, Göteborg]\n"
            + "[Lillhagsparken Södra, Göteborg]\n"
            + "[Sylte Ryrbäcksparken, Trollhättan]\n"
            + "[Skogstomtsparken, Borås]\n"
            + "[Svinesundsparken, Norge]\n"
            + "[Håjumsparken, Trollhättan]\n"
            + "[Eriksdalsparken, Bollebygd]\n"
            + "[Fridhemsparken, Lidköping]";
    final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\[([^,]++),\\s++([^\\]]++)\\]");
    final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(data);
    final Map<String, String> items = new TreeMap<>();
    while (matcher.find()) {
        items.put(matcher.group(1), matcher.group(2));
    }
    for (final Entry<String, String> entry : items.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println(entry);
    }
}
```

Output from this:

```
Boråsparken=Borås
Brunns kyrka=Ulricehamn
Brunns skola=Ulricehamn
Brunnsbotorget=Göteborg
Brunnsdal=Skövde
Brunnsgatan=Göteborg
Brunnsgården=Kungälv
Brunnshult=Mellerud
Brunnslyckan=Lerum
Brunnsnäs=Ulricehamn
Brunnsparken=Göteborg
Dalaborgsparken=Vänersborg
Eriksdalsparken=Bollebygd
Fridhemsparken=Lidköping
Håjumsparken=Trollhättan
Lillhagsparken Norra=Göteborg
Lillhagsparken Södra=Göteborg
Lysekilsparken=Lysekil
Mössebergsparken=Falköping
Rösparken=Åmål
Skogstomtsparken=Borås
Stadsparken=Ulricehamn
Svinesundsparken=Norge
Sylte Ryrbäcksparken=Trollhättan
```

You can the access the items by looping (as above) or by getting values from the `Map` by key. The `TreeMap` I have used will sort the data by key, you can also use a `LinkedHashMap` to store the data in insertion order.

You could also store the items in a `List` of tuple like structures.